# Deleting data in last cell of data in Column A

Tags: vba

I am in need of assistance agian.  When my macro works, the number 1 is populated in the final cell in column A because the coding is set up to place a number 1 or 2 depending on other data until the last row of data.  Since the last row of data has necessary information in other columns, I wanted to delete the 1 in column A because it is not needed.  How do I code to take away the value in the final cell of a column?  I've tried referencing to it and if statements.  I am sure I am missing something simple.

This is my first macro using VBA.

Thanks.

Comment: `I've tried referencing..` - show us please your attempts

Answer (score 0):

I just started working with VBA in the last day or two, but I believe the thing you are looking for is:  Cells(x,y).End(xldown).ClearContents

Alternatively, I think Range("A1").End(xldown).ClearContents would be equally effective.

But I just started doing this myself, so take with spoonful of salt.